# Problema al importar pandas y numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Tengo un problema para importar `pandas` y `numpy`. He realizado multitud de sugerencias que he encontrado en la web pero no logro solucionar el error.

Estoy usando una `Raspberrypi 4`

Tengo instalado estos paquetes en un entorno virtual:

> (venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Proyectos/08-test/src $ pip list
>
> Package         Version
>
> ---
>
> numpy           1.26.1
>
> pandas          2.1.1
>
> pip             20.3.4
>
> pkg-resources   0.0.0
>
> python-dateutil 2.8.2
>
> pytz            2023.3.post1
>
> setuptools      44.1.1
>
> six             1.16.0
>
> tzdata          2023.3

Mi Script para probar la instalación de `pandas` y `numpy` es:

```
import pandas as pd
print("Panda instalado")
```

El error:

> (venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Proyectos/08-test/src $ python3 main.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/pi/Proyectos/08-test/src/main.py", line 1, in 
> import pandas as pd
> File "/home/pi/Proyectos/08-test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 16, in 
> raise ImportError(
> ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
> numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
> its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
> your python interpreter from there.

Nota: Tambien tengo instalado tanto numpy como pandas de forma "global" es decir para usar en alguna situación
sin entorno virtual.

Comment: Cual es la salida de `python -m pip show numpy | grep '^Location: '` en el entorno?

Comment: Hola, llamando fuera del entorno virtual:
pi@raspberrypi:~/Proyectos/08-test/src $ python -m pip show numpy | grep '^Location: '
Location: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages


Y llamando desde el entorno virtual:
(venv) pi@raspberrypi:~/Proyectos/08-test $ python -m pip show numpy | grep '^Location: ' 
Location: /home/pi/Proyectos/08-test/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages

Y ejecutando el script desde mi entorno virtual me retorna el mismo error indicado.

Answer (score 1):

espero poder ayudarte. Este error parece como una advertencia de que pandas no pudo importar las dependencias requeridas, como **numpy** (en este caso).

El mensaje de error indica *"no debes intentar importar numpy desde su propio directorio"*. Parece ser un problema con la instalación de numpy o con tu entorno.

Considerando que tienes instalado numpy de forma global y en tu entorno, puede ser posible que esté ocurriendo algún conflicto con la instalación global de numpy y la versión instalada en tu entorno virtual.

Tengo entendido que la versión de numpy es crítica, y esa mezcla de versiones puede generar errores de importación como el que tienes, es importante que las versiones instaladas sean compatibles entre las bibliotecas y sus dedpendencias.

Valida la versión que tienes de numpy en tu entorno virtual y asegúrate de que coincida con la versión requerida por pandas.

```
pip show numpy
```

En caso que la versión de numpy en tu entorno virtual no coincida con la requerida por pandas puedes eliminarla.

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

Lo siguiente es asegurarte que la versión de numpy que tienes en tu entorno virtual es la que necesitas.

Finalmente recarga tu entorno virtual y confirma que numpy y pandas están instalados correctamente y valida que las rutas de importación están correctas.

Si después de todo esto sigues con el problema, lo que podrías intentar en última instacia es recrear tu entorno virtual desde cero, instalando primero numpy y luego pandas dentro del entorno virtual antes de que ejecutes tu script. Asegúrate de que no haya ninguna instalación global que pueda causar conflictos entre versiones.